# Error matching constructors when @embedding from library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to use the following @Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "transactions")
data class TransactionWithState(
        @PrimaryKey
        val hash: String,

        @Embedded
        val transaction: Transaction,

        @Embedded
        val state: TransactionState)
```

Transaction is a class from a library and creates the following problem:

```
e:   Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
e:   Transaction(org.kethereum.model.ChainDefinition,java.lang.Long,org.kethereum.model.Address,java.math.BigInteger,java.math.BigInteger,java.util.List<java.lang.Byte>,java.math.BigInteger,org.kethereum.model.Address,java.lang.String,java.math.BigInteger) : [arg0 : null, arg1 : null, arg2 : null, arg3 : null, arg4 : null, arg5 : null, arg6 : null, arg7 : null, arg8 : null, arg9 : null]
e: error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
e:
```

When I copy and paste the Transaction class over to my project it compiles fine. But this is a duplication and indirection I would like to avoid. 
First it looked like a problem with the order: 
https://github.com/walleth/kethereum/commit/fb9123c68739a315b42b3d7e57b016c7953530bf
But unfortunately this was a dead end - currently I see no way to use this class directly - would be happy about any hint on how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to change transaction to be var transaction: Transaction? instead? From the log, it would appear that 1) It cannot generate the Transaction object at all (all values are null) or 2) It's how it works, constructing an empty object and then calling the different setters

Comment: Yes - unfortunately this makes no difference :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem reported at [Google Issues Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67181813):

A workaround for now is to *create one empty constructor and all fields as var no val*

added support for **`kotlin`** using **`kotlin-metadata`**. **will go out in 1.1 alpha 2**